# Error: (FILE *) 'fp' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c

I don't know why this code is wrong. Here's the code.

```
...

int main(void)
{
    tof type;
    char FileName[260];
    printf("enter a file's name; you want to know size of this file(Maximum 260 character)\n");
    fgets(FileName,sizeof(FileName),stdin);
    Eliminate(FileName,'\n'); /*Eliminate '\n' Because '\n' remain in FileName*/
    printf("If the file's type is text, enter 1, It is binary, enter 2");
    scanf("%d",&type);

    if(type != Text && type != Binary)
        return -1;
    else if(type == Binary)
        FILE * fp = fopen(FileName,"rb");
    else if(type == Text)
        FILE * fp = fopen(FileName,"rt");

    long FileSize = SOF(fp,type);

    if(FileSize < 0)
        printf("It exceeded the limit It can calculate(about over 2GB)");
    else
        printf("Size of the file is %d byte.",FileSize);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

int SOF(FILE * subject,const tof File_type)
{
    long InitPos = ftell(subject);
    fseek(subject,0,SEEK_SET);
    long Bite = 0;
    int * Buf; //Called Buf due to fread function, little meaning
    if(File_type == Text) {
        while(fgetc(subject) != EOF && Bite >= 0)
        //When "Bite" exceed Maximum value of long type, return negative 
        {
            Bite++;
        }
    }
    else if(File_type == Binary) {
        while(fread((void*)Buf,1,1,subject) == 1 && Bite >= 0) {
            Bite++;
        }
    }
    fseek(subject,InitPos,SEEK_SET);
    return Bite;
}

...
```

('SOF' retunrns with a size of a file, 'Eliminate' is the function which eliminates some charater in some string, 'Text' and 'Binary' is declared to 1 and 2 with using enum)

The error message the compiler shows is:

> 'fp' was not decleared in this scope

But

```
if(type != Text && type != Binary)
    return -1;
else if(type == Binary)
    FILE * fp = fopen(FileName,"rb");
else if(type == Text)
    FILE * fp = fopen(FileName,"rt");
```

This code contains the declaration of FILE pointer 'fp' apparently as you can see.

Why did this error appear?

Comment: Your code is *incomplete;* in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. It's also not *minimal* - there's much in there that's irrelevant to your problem. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 5):

You declare the file *inside* the if statement. As soon as you leave that scope, the declaration is lost. You should make the declaration before the if statement

Answer (score 2):

Complement to Hack5's answer:

Instead of this:

```
if(type != Text && type != Binary)
    return -1;
else if(type == Binary)
    FILE * fp = fopen(FileName,"rb");
else if(type == Text)
    FILE * fp = fopen(FileName,"rt");
```

you want this:

```
FILE * fp;

if(type != Text && type != Binary)
    return -1;
else if(type == Binary)
    fp = fopen(FileName,"rb");
else if(type == Text)
    fp = fopen(FileName,"rt");
```

or more elegantly:

```
FILE * fp;

if(type != Text && type != Binary)
    return -1;
else 
    fp = fopen(FileName, type == Binary ? "rb" : "rt");
```

Unrelated problem:

You're going to have a problem here:

```
while(fread((void*)Buf,1,1,subject) == 1 && Bite >= 0) {
```

`Buf` points nowhere.